# Trouble importing a Python module

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and having trouble importing from a different directory.

The file I'm currently in has the path home/pi/example.py

The module I'm trying to import into this file has the path home/pi/ReactiveEngine/src/PiEngine.py

I've tried the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('home/pi/ReactiveEngine/src')
import sys.PiEngine.py
```

But it's saying there's no module named PiEngine.py

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: just `import PiEngine`!  No need sys.Piengine.py

Comment: I just tried that and now it's saying there's no module named PiEngine

Comment: Check my answer below, I tested on my machine and it worked.

Comment: :) beat you by a second

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried all of your suggestions, but it keeps coming back as "no module named PiEngine." I've used readlink -f PiEngine.py at the command line to make sure I have the file path right and it looks like I do. Anyone know why it would be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

When you import, don't put the suffix `.py`. Just do the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('home/pi/ReactiveEngine/src')
import sys.PiEngine
```

And it should work without the `.py`, because you can only import a `.py` file, so the suffix is redundant!

Or as Louis said below, you can use the following:

```
import os
os.chdir('home/pi/ReactiveEngine/src')
import PiEngine
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
import piEngine
```

If your module is named piEngine.py

Furthermore, I recommend using absolute path for `sys.path.append()`, assume that your module is in ~/home/pi/ReactiveEngine/src:

```
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~/home/pi/ReativeEngine/src'))
import piEngine
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately:

```
import os
os.chdir('home/pi/ReactiveEngine/src')
import PiEngine
```

That should solve your problem!