# cannot import a python module from a python package

Tags: python, import, module

I have this repository structure:

```
py_files_and_packages/ # normal folder 
    package/  
        module1.py # contains a class  
        module2.py
```

the `__init__.py` file of this package contains only `__author__='my name'`

The Problem:
I am trying to import the class from module1.py into model2.py. When I use
 `from package.model1 import model1`
and rung the script(model2.py) within PyCharm it works. However, when I run it from the command line it doesn't find the package. The error message: `ImportError: No module named 'my package's name'`.

I tried many tricks I found on the web such as (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22777011/2804070)but it didn't work.
I am using python-3.5.1 (installed locally), PyCharm 5.0.4 community edition, OS debian wheezy

Comment: `from .module1 import Module1Class1`

Comment: from within module2.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problom is that python can't find your package, because it is not in search path.

in model2.py, try to add the following before `from package.model1 import model1`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/py_files_and_packages')
```

so it looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/py_files_and_packages')

from package.model1 import model1

# your code here
```

Comment: thanks.. this works in all my test cases, however, after `import` i had to write the class name :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `model2.py`:

```
from module1 import your_class_name
```

Comment: my `__init__.py` is under the directory `package/`. however, it worked, thanks. But PyCharm inspector in this case tells that it cannot neither reference the module nor the class inside that module.. But it interestingly  works :)

Comment: @user2804070, that's great.